# What is Symbol Clock Frequency?

Tags: frequency, clock, display, clock-speed, intel

I came across the term Symbol Clock Frequency in [this](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel-gfx-prm-osrc-skl-vol12-display.pdf) Intel programmer reference manual (P131). I could not find what the symbol clock frequency actually is in the manual or online and thought it might be worth asking here.

Comment: The term "symbol clock" appears 11 times in that document. Are you sure you couldn't piece this together yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the clock at which bytes encoded to 8b10b TMDS symbols are sent over HDMI.
For 24-bit resolutions, pixel clock rate matches the symbol clock rate.

Edit: Quote from the linked programmer reference manual:

> The PLL output frequencies are 5x the symbol/TMDS rate, which is 1/2 the bit rate.The PLL output is divided by 5 to become the symbol/TMDS clock frequency used in the display engine.

That makes it apparent that symbol rate means the TMDS character rate, and that symbol/TMDS rate is 10x the bit rate.

Comment: You should back up your statements with quoted sources.